# How can I modify a label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to figure out a way to modify the label to print element 1 to 4 in a line and repeat. I have attached a picture to hopefully clarify what I am trying to accomplish.

My goal is to make the results look like the following

**`1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D`**

**`1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d`**

[image]

```
my_entries = []

#prints the result
def something():
   entry_list =''
   index = 0
   for entries in my_entries:
      index+=1
      print(entries.get() + ' ' +str(index))
      entry_list = entry_list + str(index) + ' ' + str(entries.get()) + '\n'
      if index == 4:
         index = 0
      my_label.config(text=entry_list)
   
   #prints the element
   print('\n'+my_entries[1].get())


def get_value():
    my_entries.clear()
    value = vialEntry.get()
    try:
        #print(int(value))
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None

#this function will create the inputs for the vials elements 
def make_entry():  
   num = get_value()
   print(num)
   tk.Label(master, text = "Name ").grid(row=1, column=1)
   tk.Label(master, text = "Time ").grid(row=1, column=2)
   tk.Label(master, text = "Temp ").grid(row=1, column=3)
   tk.Label(master, text = "Freq ").grid(row=1, column=4)
   #row loop
   for y in range(num):
      #column loop
      for x in range(4):
         user_entery = Entry(master)
         tk.Label(master, text = "Element: "+str(y+1)).grid(row=y+2, column=0, pady=5)
         user_entery.grid(row=y+2, column=x+1, pady=0, padx=5)
         my_entries.append(user_entery)

#end of make_entry function

my_button = Button(master, text="Click me", command=something)
my_button.grid(row=23, column=0, pady=20)
tk.Label(master, text = "Results: ").grid(row=24, column=0)
my_label = Label(master, text='')
my_label.grid(row=25, column=0, pady=0)
```

Comment: If you don't want newlines in the labels, why are you putting newlines in the labels?

Comment: I made new line so it would be easy to read if I take it out, it will just display it in one line.

Comment: There's no need to put newlines in the `Label`s in order to do that. Your question is unclear. It sounds like what you really want to know is how to **position** the `Label`s in a row.

Comment: It seems a little strange that your GUI program is printing results. Regardless, where does this printing take place in your code?

Comment: it takes place in the function something(). I am just printing what ever the user inputs in the entry boxes. The entry boxes are made in the make_entry() function

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: I don't understand the comment _"if I take it out, it will just display it on one line"_ - I thought you were asking how to display it in one line, so why is that a problem?

Comment: its because it will print 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 I want it to do 1 2 3 4 new line 1 2 3 4 new line and so on

Comment: What is stopping you from adding a newline every four items instead of every item?

Comment: I tried to do it but it will only print last element which only prints the 4th item only. For some reason I cant figure it out

Comment: First, try to write an ordinary console program that `print`s the necessary data. Then adapt that to the Tkinter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `\n` after each index/value pair.  You need to add `\n` after 4 index/value pairs instead:

```py
def something():
   entry_list =''
   index = 0
   for entries in my_entries:
      index+=1
      print(entries.get() + ' ' + str(index))
      entry_list += str(index) + ' ' + str(entries.get())
      if index == 4:
         index = 0
         entry_list += '\n'
      else:
         entry_list += ' '

   my_label.config(text=entry_list)

   #prints the element
   print('\n'+my_entries[1].get())
```

Note that the for loop can be simplified as below:

```py
def something_():
    entry_list = ''
    for i, entry in enumerate(my_entries):
        entry_list += f'{i%4+1} {entry.get()}' + ('\n' if i%4 == 3 else ' ')
    # or one-liner
    #entry_list = ''.join(f'{i%4+1} {entry.get()}' + ('\n' if i%4 == 3 else ' ') for i,entry in enumerate(my_entries))
    my_label.config(text=entry_list)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for and thank you for simplifying the for loop.